# Game of Thrones reference in One piece

Tags: one-piece

I can't find which episode it was but in "Impel down" I feel like I saw the same throne we can see on the TV show Game of Thrones, is it related or not or maybe just a coincidence ?

Comment: Could you provide a better reference to the scene? I. E. Who was sitting on it when in the impel down arc did it happen?

Comment: I remember Mr. 3 was giving keys to the inmates to get out of Impel Down, and nobody was siting on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chapter 525 titled "The Underwater Prison Impel Down" which started the arc out got released on 8th of December 2008. The first episode of the Game of Thrones TV series aired in 2011, so there's no chance it could reference anything from it.

Comment: Do you have a picture of the throne I was talking about ?

Comment: The first book has been released in 1996 and since the iron throne is described quite detailed, it would still be possible.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Game_of_Thrones

Comment: @ibkr Do you remember which level it was on?

Comment: @Bálint Sorry I don't remember the level, I just remember what they was doing at this moment.

Comment: @ibkr They were pretty much freeing people through the whole arc. Do you remember maybe the characteristic of the level? Cold, hot, etc?